# opening two folders and displaying images php

Tags: php

I've got the problem of trying to display two albums of photos from a db using php. Currently the following code works but for just one album. Basically I need it to display photos from 'mount-everest-part-2' aswell.

```
<?php

$path = "images/galleries/";
$album = 'mount-everest-part-1';

if ($handle = opendir($path.$album.'/thumbs/')) { 
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
       if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file, 0, 2) != '._') { 
           $files[] = $file; 
       } 
   } 
   closedir($handle); 
}
asort($files);

foreach($files as $file) { 
        echo '<li><a href="../' . $path . $album . '/images/' . $file . '" rel="shadowbox['.$album.']"><img src="../' . $path . $album . '/thumbs/' . $file . '" /></a></li>'; 
}

?>
```

How can I use this code to open two files and spit the files out using the same foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like one of those things that OOP would suit nicely. Here's an example:

```
<?php
    class Album_Picture_File {
        private $fileName;
        private $path;
        private $album;

        public function __construct($fileName, $path, $album) {
            $this->fileName = $fileName;
            $this->path = $path;
            $this->album = $album;
        }

        private function getAlbumPath() {
            return '../' . $this->path . $this->album;
        }

        public function getPicturePath() {
            return $this->getAlbumPath() . '/images/' . $this->fileName;
        }

        public function getThumbnailPath() {
            return $this->getAlbumPath() . '/thumbs/' . $this->fileName;
        }
    }

    function fetchFiles($path, $album) {
        $files = array();
        if ($handle = opendir($path.$album.'/thumbs/')) { 
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file, 0, 2) != '._') { 
                    $fullPath = $path . $album . '/thumbs/' . $file;
                    $files[$fullPath] = new Album_Picture_File($file, $path, $album); 
                } 
            } 
            closedir($handle); 
        }
        ksort($files); //sort after key (out file path)
        return $files;
    }

    $files = array_merge(
        fetchFiles('images/galleries/', 'mount-everest-part-1'),
        fetchFiles('images/galleries/', 'mount-everest-part-2')
    );

    foreach($files as $file) { 
        echo '<li><a href="' . $file->getPicturePath() . '" rel="shadowbox['.$album.']"><img src="' . $file->getThumbnailPath() . '" /></a></li>'; 
    }
?>
```

Note that instead of pushing `$files` with strings, we push it with `Album_Picture_File` objects.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. My php skills are very basic so this is a way over my head :(

Comment: @RobMorris This uses classes. Classes are objects that you can add data/functions to individually (as well as other things such as traits/static/etc. etc., but don't worry about that for now), and they can contain their own private variables (which is why `$this->fileName` is different per file). I'd recommend you to read [PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) as it's amazing once you get to know it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm a front end dev so this is a little scary to me! I would like to get to know php and php oop though. Maybe i need a teacher like you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a global array :

```
$all = array();
```

Then, make 2 loops and push the global array (create a function that reads the directory for example)

```
$files_dir_one = getFiles("your_dir");
$files_dir_two = getFiles("your_dir2");

$all = array_merge($files_dir_one, $files_dir_two);

function getFiles($directory) {
$files = array();
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) { 
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
       if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file, 0, 2) != '._') { 
           $files[] = $file; 
       } 
   } 
   closedir($handle); 

}
//asort($files);
return $files;

}
```

And then, the last step : populate the view

Comment: After reviewing this, it's a bit more than that. The question is most likely to broad. However if you like to answer it: The information in which album the file is placed is is needed next to the filename so that populating the view possible. I don't have the time to present the right code so removed my answer as it was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use this code to open two files and spit the files out using the same foreach loop?

Taking your question literally it works like this. First of all extract a function with the two input variables:

```
/**
 * @param string $path
 * @param string $album
 */
function list_images($path, $album) {
    $files = [];

    if ($handle = opendir($path . $album . '/thumbs/'))
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file, 0, 2) != '._')
            {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    asort($files);

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        echo '<li><a href="../' . $path . $album . '/images/' . $file . '" rel="shadowbox[' . $album . ']"><img src="../' . $path . $album . '/thumbs/' . $file . '" /></a></li>';
    }
}
```

Then you can just iterate over your two albums and output both:

```
$path   = "images/galleries/";
$albums = ['mount-everest-part-1', 'mount-everest-part-2'];

foreach ($albums as $album)
{
    list_images($path, $album);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a bit too soon to start using `$files = []` in examples as it's a 5.4 feature and [*accordingly* only ~8% use 5.4+](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5/all)?